# toggle the grid cells value, ASP.net 3.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-3.5

For my web application,

I want a 10*10 (100 cells which is created dynamically) grid to be displayed in the following manner.

1. Initially all the cells' color is green.
2. If i click on any cell its color becomes red if it is green and if i click again it becomes red.(Toggle the cell color)
3. I should be able to display dynamic number of link buttons in each cell.On the click of which it pop ups a window.

Are there any control available for this? Or how can I implement this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this behavior very easily using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).

You might want to look into some function like:

- [Click](http://api.jquery.com/click/)
- [Toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)
- [Live](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

I don't recommend you to do it with C#, you would have to place an UpdatePanel and cause a postback just to change the cell colors.